# Connect remotely to cpanel Database with php

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to access to the database of my live website from localhost. My website is working on cpanel hosting. 
I created database and added user to that database but can not connect to this database from my localhost . 
this is the code of database information

```
<?php
    $conf['dbuser']='admin_root';
    $conf['dbpass']='rootroot!@#$';
    $conf['dbname']='bsaiiian_os';
    $conf['dbhost']='example.com';
    $conf["title"]='DEMO';
?>
```

I think the problem is from `$conf['dbhost']` variable where I'm putting the url of my site and not sure if that is right.
When I'm uploading my script to the hosting and put

```
$conf['dbhost']='localhost';
```

the connection is established .
this is error message:

> Connection failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons cPanel's MySQL requires that you allow your IP in order to have access.

This is done through:

**cPanel -> Remote MySQL Connection**

You need to navigate there and allow your local computer's IP in order to make the connection.

Side Note: This stands true for all IPs, even the server's one that your account is hosted on. You will see your cPanel account's IP already present in there - this is to allow access to MySQL for any files from your cPanel account